# firefox not displaying youtube videos correctly in Linux Mint 15 olivia

Tags: firefox, chrome, youtube

I'm running Linux mint 15 olivia, Xfce 32-bit version. I try to access youtube videos in the latest Firefox, but the videos displays incorrectly for some reason. I do have flash installed, but I see there is more than one flash plugin that can be installed when I go the software manager. I installed Google Chrome also and there youtube videos displays correctly, I can watch the videos as normal. Why is this? What can I do to fix firefox? I can see that I have shockwave player also installed.

Comment: Can you look at the options provided here?  https://wiki.debian.org/FlashPlayer

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are having difficulty is that Adobe [stopped releasing Flash for Linux](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html):

> For Flash Player releases after 11.2, the Flash Player browser plug-in
>   for Linux will only be available via the "Pepper" API as part of the
>   Google Chrome browser distribution and will no longer be available as
>   a direct download from Adobe. Adobe will continue to provide security
>   updates to non-Pepper distributions of Flash Player 11.2 on Linux for
>   five years from its release.

The reason it works with Chrome is that it is part of the browser distribution.

Things don't look so hot for on-going support as noted in the [Mozilla Support forums](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/959414) and elsewhere. There are work-around hacks in that thread, but I wouldn't depend on them.

Comment: Well it's probably a good thing anyway....we didn't need their dang proprietary formats _anyway_! (goes and cries in corner)  =)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going to http://www.youtube.com/html5 and setting Youtube videos to play with HTML5. I don't think all videos have this functionality yet (I'm not sure), but this is probably your most futureproof option.